# Как можно сократить код в Lazarus

Tags: delphi, pascal, lazarus

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if (edit1.text <> '') and (edit2.text <> '') and (edit3.text <> '') 
  and (edit4.text <> '') and (edit5.text <> '') and (edit6.text <> '') then
  begin
    label5.visible := true;   
  end
  else begin
    label5.visible := true;
    label5.caption := 'Введіть усі значення';
  end;
end;
```

Как можно сократить строчку кода при проверки на наличие в Edit значения?

Comment: У вас `label5.visible := true;` в обеих ветках

Comment: Если не группировать, как Alex предлагает, то тут всю концепцию надо менять. Например, один OnChange для всех эдитов взводит соответствующие флаги -например, биты в слове состояния согласно тэгу. Это подойдёт и для случая полусотни эдитов.

Comment: получить все контролы формы, проверить что они edit и если они edit смотреть задано ли там что-то

Answer (score 3):

1. Если у нас в `if then else` в обеих ветках присваивается значение одной и той же булевой переменной, то ей сразу можно присвоить условие из if (или его отрицание)
2. Остальные действия можно выполнить опираясь уже на значение этой переменной.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  label5.visible := (edit1.text <> '') and (edit2.text <> '') and (edit3.text <> '')
                and (edit4.text <> '') and (edit5.text <> '') and (edit6.text <> '');
      
  if label5.visible then
    label5.caption := 'Введіть усі значення';
end;
```

Comment: только лучше использовать отдельную булевую переменную.  Да, это плюс одна строка, но код будет чище, и красивее. Плюс, имя булевой переменной может самодокументировать код.

Comment: @KoVadim, еще и эффективнее будет, так как установка/чтение свойств визуальных компонентов зачастую работает через сообщения окну с ожиданием ответа. Но вопрос был исключительно о длине кода.

Comment: я думаю, это не то место, где нужно гнаться за длинной кода.  Но если уже решили, тогда есть возможность написать намного короче (-40 символов!) `label5.visible := (edit1.length + edit1.length + edit1.length + edit1.length + edit1.length + edit1.length) <> 0;` (а если пробелы убрать...)

Comment: @KoVadim, это не эквивалентные условия. В вашем получается связка по `or`, то есть истинно, если заполнен хотя бы один.

Comment: Да не вопрос. Просто на умножить заменить

Answer (score 2):

Похоже, что серебряной пули нет, и сильно сократить это выражение не получится.

Если контролов действительно **много**, то можно попробовать два пути:

- поместить все контролы в один контейнер (например, Panel) и итерировать все объекты этого Panel;
- присвоить всем контролам определённый тег и итерировать по этому тегу.

К сожалению, в данном примере оба этих варианта окажутся ещё более громоздкими, чем исходный ‍♂️

Источник с примерами:
http://www.delphigroups.info/2/5b/524909.html

Answer (score 0):

Немного не дописан код, потому что в обоих случаях `label5.visible := true;`, если же label5 отвечает только за то чтобы отображать текущее сообщение, тогда текст можно присвоить изначально (в `Object Inspector'e` свойство `caption` компонента `Label5`), а в коде управлять только свойством `Visible`. В таком случае получится следующее:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  label5.visible := (edit1.text <> '') and (edit2.text <> '') and (edit3.text <> '') 
  and (edit4.text <> '') and (edit5.text <> '') and (edit6.text <> '') then
end;
```

Если вчитаться в вопрос, нужно сократить строчку кода при проверке на наличие в Edit значения. То есть нас интересует только проверка, а не весь код.

Согласен, такой код сложно поддерживать, и дублирования много, так что можно вынести логику проверки в отдельный метод, тогда в основной части действительно будет меньше кода, решение не универсальное, потому что при добавлении нового элемента - нужно его добавлять в список. Как сделать универсальным - уже подсказали в комментариях (панель, теги, события....).

```
function IsEmpty(controls: array of TEdit): boolean;
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  Result := False;
  for I := 0 to Length(controls) - 1 do
    if Trim(controls[I].Text) = '' then
       Exit(true);
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
    label5.visible := Not IsEmpty([Edit1, Edit2, Edit3, Edit4, Edit5, Edit6]);
end;
```

`Trim` - можно убрать, просто проверка на пробелы